# QWebKit + XPath + HTML. Is it possible?

Tags: html, qt, parsing, tidy, qwebkit

Is it possible to parse HTML (HTML/HTML5, not XHTML) pages using XPath and Qt classes of QWebkit (and probably other standard or Qt classes) without using any external utilities like tidy?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, obviously. XPath is for well-formed XML, which HTML is not (besides XHTML that you specifically excluded).

For accessing the DOM tree of a QtWebkit page, you have to use QtWebkit's `QWebElement` api.

You can access the document element with

```
QWebElement QWebView::page()->mainFrame()->documentElement();
```